# Why my route is not working in production server

Tags: laravel, routes, hosting

Everything is running nice from local to hosting server and when I deploy the project on the server, I'am getting this error message.

My form code with the route :
`<form action="{{ route('email.send')}}" method="post" class="w-full">`
my route on web.php : `Route::post('send',[ContactController::class,'send'])->name('email.send');`

and then the error on production :
[image]

the php artisan route:list result
[image]

Is there any solution for this issue?
Thank

Comment: Did you run `php artisan optimize:clear` on your server? If not then run it.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: @Aless55 thanks!!! everything running nice